The Switching regulator stops working after random minutes
I've used TPS562242 regulator to step down from 12V battery input, to around 5.6V for two linear regulators (TLV767, 3.3V and 5V). However, the switching regulator stops working after around 1 to 15 minutes. It works fine in the first minutes. Re-powering it won't help quickly but sometimes works after an unknown amount of time. Sometimes I hear a bit noise coming out of 3.3uH inductor.
What have I done:

Tried on multiple boards with brand-new regulators from trusted suppliers (digikey)
No load connected, just a microcontroller
Nothing gets hot, the maximum current is around 5 mA and it's limited by power supply to around 100 mA for safe work

What I suspect:

I left the EN pin float, datasheet says it's OK
There are a lot of features on this regulator like UVLO, OCP, ECO mode ... and I'm not sure if they get enabled somehow or what they do

The PCB and schematic layout, both top and bottom copper are GND plane:


Any suggestion on the cause?

Overheating? How hot does it get? Does EN drop?

What happens to the input voltage when it goes bad?

@winny no heat at all.as much as I can sense with my finger. I didn't check the EN pin.

@Andyaka The input is either fed with a CC-controlled power supply or a high current lithium battery. I didn't find any change in the voltage after the problem occurred

Probe the switch node with a scope, see what's going on there.

And probe EN while at it. Ideally you want to capture the moment it shuts down.

See the section on layout guidelines:  "Do not allow switching current to flow under the device."

@JohnBirckhead Yepp after testing many aspects, it narrows down to this horrible mistake I made.
